# Way to retrieve parameter value?

Tags: python

Im currently trying to print out the parameter value after given an argument.
(This is example code)

```
def greet(lang):
    if lang == 'es':
        print('hola')
    elif lang == 'fr':
        print('bonjour')
    else:
        print('Hello')
    return lang

greet(input('Insert Language .... '))
print('Your language is ' , lang)
```

After trying to do it this way I receive a name error. I understand that if i put the print statement inside of the function, error solved, but I would like to be able to grab the value from anywhere in case I may need it. I'm new here so please go easy on me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the last two lines:

```
def greet(lang):
    if lang == 'es':
        print('hola')
    elif lang == 'fr':
        print('bonjour')
    else:
        print('Hello')
    return lang

inp = input('Insert Language .... ')
greet(inp)
print('Your language is ' , inp)
```

In your code, your input couldn't be accessed because it was not assigned to any variable.

Answer (score 0):

Just store the value of the user input in a variable, and use that variable whenever you want, like so:

```
def greet(lang):
    if lang == 'es':
        print('hola')
    elif lang == 'fr':
        print('bonjour')
    else:
        print('Hello')

lang = input('Insert Language .... ')
greet(lang)
print('Your language is ' , lang)
```

By the way, you don't need a return statement in your greet() function, as the return is not meant to be stored anywhere. lang is already known to the program and does not need to be returned.

Comment: Not really, I specify why the return is not needed in the greet() function ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want

```py
def greet(lang):
    if lang == 'es':
        print('hola')
    elif lang == 'fr':
        print('bonjour')
    else:
        print('Hello')
    return lang

print('Your language is ', greet(input('Insert Language .... ')))
```